# Как сделать правильный горизонтальный скролл?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать данную горизонтальную таблицу, что бы таблица была со скролом, а страница оставалась неподвижной по горизонтали Y. И важно что бы страница оставалась неподвижной для мониторов, планшетов и телефонов.[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.scroll{
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div >
<p class=scroll>
  asfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf
</p>

</div>
```